# Error while trying to open the pdf file using openPDF editior

Tags: c#

i have multiple pdf readers installed in my machine. i want to open the pdf file using OpenPDF editor. which need to be as my default reader. i am struck at creating the instance for openPDF. can anyone help me with this how to create instance for the application to read the text in "C# code". 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What does your current code look like? What is the error message? Without any context we can't help you.

Comment: I dont have code for this. I request anyone to send code for the above issue.

Comment: this is not how Stackoverflow works. It's not a code bazar and the chance of getting what you want through this channel is rather small. Just sayin' .